# PHP script wont run

Tags: php

So I got this php script on my linux machine, when running it, it just "hangs"

[Y IT DO DIS?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1za2d.png)

I have installed all the needed PHP dependencies needed, I also have the "settings.php" in the same folder, used (chmod 777) on the folders and files. 
Code:

```
<?php
$f = fopen( 'php://stdin', 'r' );
while( $input = fgets( $f ) ) {
//while( $input = readline() ) {
  if ($pid = pcntl_fork()) { return; }
  acctstart($input);
  fclose($f);
}

function acctstart($input) {
  require_once("settings.php");
  $input = $input;

  $delimiter1 = "The new session";
  $delimiter2 = "has been created";
  $pos1 = strpos($input, $delimiter1) + strlen($delimiter1) + 2;
  $pos2 = strpos($input, $delimiter2) - 2;
  $sstrlen = $pos2 - $pos1;
  $sessid = substr($input, $pos1, $sstrlen);

  exec($vpncmd." ".$softetherip." /SERVER /HUB:".$hubname." /PASSWORD:".$apipass." /CSV /CMD SessionGet ".$sessid, $SessionGet);

  if(strpos($SessionGet[0],"rror occurred") != FALSE) { die("Error - SessionGet resulted in error"); }
  foreach ($SessionGet as $line){
    list($key,$val) = explode(",",$line,2);
    $result[$key] = $val;
  }


  $recheck = 0;
  dhcptest:
  sleep(2);
  exec($vpncmd." ".$softetherip." /SERVER /HUB:".$hubname." /PASSWORD:".$apipass." /CSV /CMD IpTable", $IpTable);
  $ok=0;
  foreach ($IpTable as $line){
    if(strpos($line,$sessid)){
      if(strpos($line,"DHCP")){
        list(,$key,$val) = explode(",",$line);
        list($framedip) = explode(" ",$val);
        #$result2[$key] = $val;
        $ok=1;
      }
    }
  }


  if($ok==0){
    if($recheck==4) {die("Error - could not find session in retrived IpTable data");}
    sleep(2);
    $recheck = $recheck + 1;
    goto dhcptest;
  }


        if( file_exists( $database ) )
        {
                echo "The file $filename exists";
        }
        else
        {
                echo "The file $filename does not exist";
        }

  $db = new SQLite3($database);

  $db->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sessions (sessionid varchar(255), username varchar (255), clientip varchar (255), inputoctets varchar (255), ' .
            'outputoctets varchar (255), framedip varchar (255), nasip varchar (255), nasport varchar (255), acctstarttime varchar (255), '.
            'acctsessiontime varchar (255), PRIMARY KEY(sessionid))');
  $query = $db->escapeString('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO sessions (sessionid, username, clientip, inputoctets, outputoctets, framedip, nasip, nasport, acctstarttime, acctsessiontime) VALUES ("'.$sessid.'","'.$result["User Name (Authentication)"].'","'.$result["Client IP Address"].'",NULL,NULL,"'.$framedip.'","'.$result["Server IP Address (Reported)"].'","'.$result["Server Port (Reported)"].'","'.$result["Connection Started at"].'",NULL)');
  $db->exec($query);

  $sessid = $db->escapeString($sessid);
  $results = $db->querySingle("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE sessionid = '".$sessid."'", true);

  $tmpfname = tempnam($tmpdir, "acctstarttmp_");
  $handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");

  $packet = "Service-Type = Framed-User"."\n".
            "Framed-Protocol = PPP"."\n".
            "NAS-Port = ".$results['nasport']."\n".
            "NAS-Port-Type = Async"."\n".
            "User-Name = '".$results['username']."'"."\n".
            "Calling-Station-Id = '".$results['clientip']."'"."\n".
            "Called-Station-Id = '".$results['nasip']."'"."\n".
            "Acct-Session-Id = '".$sessid."'"."\n".
            "Framed-IP-Address = ".$results['framedip']."\n".
            "Acct-Authentic = RADIUS"."\n".
            "Event-Timestamp = ".time()."\n".
            "Acct-Status-Type = Start"."\n".
            "NAS-Identifier = '".$results['nasip']."'"."\n".
            "Acct-Delay-Time = 0"."\n". // handle?
            "NAS-IP-Address = ".$results['nasip']."\n";
  fwrite($handle, $packet);
  fclose($handle);
  exec("radclient ".$radiussrv.":".$radiusport." acct ".$radiuspass." -f ".$tmpfname);
  unlink($tmpfname);


  $db->close();
}
//fclose( $f );

?>
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Regards,

Comment: To post your code, just plop it in here, highlight it, and press the button for the squigly brackets {}

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of things, it "hangs" because it's waiting for user input (aka typing on the keyboard)

Comment: Indeed it was haha :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use curl in console? That particulary executes your php file.

For example, if you're want to dump header, use this:

```
curl -D /var/radius/acctstart.php
```

If you're not installed curl, just use this method for Debian

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

And to check PHP errors it is the best way to use this site:

http://www.phpcodechecker.com